# Create View using two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

1. I want to create a view  (total loan amount - total deposit amount)
   using table **loan_b** and **deposit_b**  how it possible?
2. and create another view ,  parentage (20%) of each loan  using loan_b table.
   the table are given below:

Here are the queries I'm using for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE loan_b( cust_id VARCHAR2(10), loan_id VARCHAR2(10), loan_amount NUMBER(10) ); 

INSERT INTO loan_b VALUES(100,'100A',28500);

INSERT INTO loan_b VALUES(102,'100B',2500);

CREATE TABLE deposit_b( cust_id VARCHAR2(10), deposit_amount NUMBER(10) ); 

INSERT INTO deposit_b VALUES(99,51700); 

INSERT INTO deposit_b VALUES(99,2462);

INSERT INTO deposit_b VALUES(55,55200);
```

Comment: In the first view which relation there are between the tables ?

Comment: @scaisEdge yes relation using by cust_id , but i want to do with out relation ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easly create  a view as select  then once you have definited the select you need you can create you view  eg:

```
create view your_view_name as 
select 
   a.cust_id cust_id
 , a.loan_id load_id
 , a.loan_amount loan_amount
 , b.deposit_amount deposit_amount
from loan_b a
inner join deposit_b on a.cust_id = b.cust_id;
```

or if you need only the sum

```
create view your_view_name2 as 
select 
   sum(a.loan_amount) sum_loan_amount
 , sum(b.deposit_amount)  sum_deposit_amount
from loan_b a
inner join deposit_b on a.cust_id = b.cust_id;
```

and for diff you should use  (i have changed the table alias with the original tablename)

```
create view your_view_name3 as 
select 
   loan_b.loan_amount - deposit_b.deposit_amount   diff_load_deposit_amount
from loan_b 
inner join deposit_b on loan_b.cust_id = deposit_b.cust_id;
```

Comment: what is **a.** and **b.** ?

Comment: no need some  need Subtraction (total loan amount - total deposit amount) using table** loan_b** and **deposit_b**

Comment: a. and b. are simply alias  of the table name  ... but as i write at the begin  .. once you know the select yiu need then the view is easly created .... anyway i have update the answer

Comment: i am  tired trying this what is **from loan_b a** ? i can without inner join? and i can to parentage operation ??

Comment: The from loan_b a ii mistake a.. i have update the answer .. using inner join  deposit_b on loan_b.cust_id = deposit_b.cust_id; or   from loan_b ,   deposit_bwhere  deposit_b on loan_b.cust_id = deposit_b.cust_id;  is the same  ..

Comment: Hello @scaisEdge view create successfully and ok, But i need  Subtraction ** total loan amount - total deposit amount**